# android studio set up is not working

Tags: android

This the properties of "my computer"
[image]

This is the set up of sdk manager:

[image]

This is the avd error message:

[image]

This is the check using havdetectiontool:
[image]

Also: I do not see any virtualization option in my bios setting.

My question: Can I make AVD working ?

Comment: using the Android SDK Manager is not enough to install HAXM. The SDK Manager just downloads the installer but does not actually install it. You need to either find the installer it downloaded in your SDK folder under tools/intel or install it from [intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x).

Comment: Alternatively, I would strongly recommend you use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/), as it's much faster.

Comment: Oh, I just saw that [your processor doesn't support virtualization (VT-x)](http://ark.intel.com/products/50175/Intel-Pentium-Processor-P6100-3M-Cache-2_00-GHz). In this case, you're stuck with the incredibly slow ARM images, as mentioned in the answer by Harsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can download and use `ARM images` that do not need hardware virtualization instead of using `x86 system images`. Need to tell you that ARM images will be very slow compared to x86 images.

You can download `ARM image` of respective APIs by selecting this option.

[image: SDK Manager]

Comment: Could you please give me the link from where I can download ARM images?

Answer (score 1):

86 emulation require hardware visualization.it seams yous computer don't have hardware virtualization Technology you can refer [here](http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology) for Intel processor supporting visualization Technology.your intel p6100 do not have hardware virtualization.You can chose a ARM CPU with ARM EABI System image Instead of 86 Atom CPU with Intel 86x Atom System Image. 
The Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM) will not work on your computer look [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/50175/Intel-Pentium-Processor-P6100-3M-Cache-2_00-GHz) for more detail over your processor.